# Setting dynamic values to jQuery UI vertical slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a series of images and I want to use a slider to browse between those images. When I open the series I want to set some values to the slider but I cannot make it work.

I have two problems: 
- how to access the slider
- how to set up the values

This is how I tried:

```
$(slider).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
        }).addClass("dhSlider");



$(slider).slider( "option", "max", this.series.images.length);
$(slider).slider( "option", "min", 0 );
$(slider).slider( "option", "step",this.series.images.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not initializing the slider correctly.you need to give class or id of div which you want as slider:

**HTML:**

```
<p>
<label for="amount">Slider Range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>

<div id="myslider" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
  <script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#myslider" ).slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  range: true,
  values: [ startvalueselected, endvalueselected],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
 });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#myslider" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#myslider" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
 });
 </script>
```

**[see JqueryUI vertical Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical)**

Comment: everything is created dynamically I don't have any HTML

Comment: this doesn't work
 slider = document.createElement("div");
        slider.id="mySlider";